# Python to Blocks in Blockly

Tags: python, typescript, blockly

I run edublocks.org and I'd like to implement Python to Blocks. Currently, you can only move from Blocks to Python.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a library that implements this:
https://github.com/blockpy-edu/BlockMirror

You can try out this live demo: https://blockpy-edu.github.io/BlockMirror/docs/index.html

I found it under this thread:
https://groups.google.com/g/blockly/c/A6MU3pzkjuw?pli=1

Now just got to figure out how to load this code into pyramid app, and pull the python code into blockly, modify in blockly, save back to python.